# Automatically deleting files that haven't been accessed in 30 days

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, delete-file

I have a batch file that I am trying have delete files in a specific location that have not been accessed for 30 days. It currently deletes files that were created over 30 days ago, which is not what I want.

My code is:

```
 REM Remove files older than 30 days
forfiles /p "DOCUMENT LOCATION" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" 
/d -30
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm assuming it is a quick fix if it is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: The last access timestamp is not reliable. There are various paths by which a file can be accessed, yet the timestamp is not updated. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: Is there a way to go off of date modified then?

Comment: By default, Windows no longer updates the "last access" timestamp at all.  You'd first need to turn that functionality on - or a more reliable one like security auditing.  Even then, I don't think it would be easy to use from batch.